# How to overwirte Catalog model in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides, model, plugin

I try to overwrite  get_url() function located in **item.php** from this path `\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item.php`

To overwrite this function I fount 2 ways, with **PREFERANCES** and **PLUGINS**

I want to use PLUGIN method, and i found this example :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
            <plugin name="yourcompany-yourmodule-product-model" type="YourCompany\YourModule\Plugin\ProductPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
        </type>    
    </config>

**and** 


<?php

namespace YourCompany\YourModule\Plugin;

class ProductPlugin
{    
    public function beforeSetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $name)
    {
        // logging to test override    
        $logger = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
        $logger->debug('Model Override Test before');

        return $name;
    }

    public function afterGetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {            
        // logging to test override    
        $logger = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
        $logger->debug('Model Override Test after');

        return $result;
    }    
}
?>
```

But i don't know how will be for my **item.php** file. can anyone tell me how to modify this example to fit with my issue?

Answer (score 1):

In di.xml add this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item">
        <plugin name="logProductName" type="\Ktpl\Blog\Plugin\Item" />
    </type>
</config>
```

After that create file Ktpl\Blog\Plugin\Item.php and add following code

```
<?php

namespace Ktpl\Blog\Plugin;

class Item
{
    public function afterGetUrl(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item $item)
    {
        // write logic you want for Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item:getUrl() method
    }  

    public function beforeGetUrl(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item $item)
    {
        // write logic you want for Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item:getUrl() method
    }  
}
```

Comment: I added your code, and afeter this i get black page. i check the err and i get [03-Apr-2017 09:36:23 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Sitename\CartNotification\Plugin\CategoryPlugin::getFilter() in /home/site/www/producten/app/code/site/CartNotification/Plugin/CategoryPlugin.php:10
Stack trace:.

Comment: you call getFilter() function in CategoryPlugin.ph‌​p file but getFilter()  is not define in home/site/www/producten/app/code/site/CartNotification/Plug‌​in/CategoryPlugin.ph‌​p file

Comment: plugin allow you to change method's logic but it's not extend class so getFilter() is not found in plugin class you need to create object of Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: because all the function that i use in this class have the same problem as getFilter()

Comment: U will get same error for every function because Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item object is not created.You need to ask other question how to create object for Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item  because i dont know much about creating object but you can try to extend Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item

Comment: Ex.  class Item extends Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item